# Representing keyboard as 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, keyboard

hope you can help!

Here's the relevant code:

This code initializes the keyboard as a 3d array:

```
KeyboardRow1 = ["`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "="]
KeyboardRow2 = ["", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]", ""]
KeyboardRow3 = ["", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", ";", ""] 
KeyboardRow4 = ["", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "/"]
KeyboardRow1S = ["~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+"]
KeyboardRow2S = ["", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "{", "}", "|"]
KeyboardRow3S = ["","A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ":", ""] 
KeyboardRow4S = ["", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "<", ">", "?", ""]
Array2R = [KeyboardRow1, KeyboardRow2, KeyboardRow3, KeyboardRow4]
Array2S = [KeyboardRow1S, KeyboardRow2S, KeyboardRow3S, KeyboardRow4S]
Array3 = [Array2R, Array2S]
```

This code asks for user to input a string:

```
Password = getpass.getpass("Enter a password: ")
```

This code finds where each character of the password is in the array and appends the values of its coordinates in the array into KeyboardPositions

```
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
z = 0
KeyboardPositions = []

for z in range(0,PasswordLength):

    for i in range(0,1):

        if Password[z] == str(Array3[i][j][k]):
            KeyboardPositions.append((i,j,k))

        for j in range(0,2):

            if Password[z] == str(Array3[i][j][k]):
                KeyboardPositions.append((i,j,k))

            for k in range (0,12):

                if Password[z] == str(Array3[i][j][k]):
                    KeyboardPositions.append((i,j,k))
```

When I run the code, it works fine for the first two rows of the keyboard. If the password is qwerty, the contents of the array (as expected) are [(0,1,1),(0,1,2),(0,1,3),(0,1,4),(0,1,5),(0,1,6)]. The first of the three coordinates is is whether or not shift is held, the second is the row and the third is the column.

If I type in something like asdfg , zxcvb or ASD it will not work. KeyboardPositions will be empty. Anything from the third or fourth row and anything with shift held will not work.

Comment: What do the repeated `if Password[z] == str(Array3[i][j][k]):
            KeyboardPositions.append((i,j,k))` do?

Comment: Password[z] checks each character in the password, z cycles from index 0 to password length.

That piece checks to see if the character is in the array, and if it is: it will store the coordinates (i, j, k) in KeyboardPositions.

It's supposed to cycle through i , j and k to search the entire array I guess

Comment: but it does the same thing 3 times, repeatedly in each loop.

Comment: When it does it in the first loop, only i has cycled - j and k are still 0. When it does it in the second loop, i and j have both cycled - k is still 0. When it does it in the last loop, they have all cycled. This way, it checks for all permutations for i, j and k. At least that's how I intended it to work ...

Comment: if you put it just once in the inner loop it will still do what you want.

Comment: It does indeed! Thanks for helping me simplify it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `range` arguments.  There are a couple of errors in them.  Remember, `range(0, n)` runs from `0` through `n-1`, and excludes `n` itself.  So `range(0,1)` only includes `0`.  For `range(0,2)`, I assume you want to iterate from `0` through `3`, inclusive, so you want `range(0,4)`, or just `range(4)`.

Comment: Just got it to work! Thanks alot
It turns out that the last row has less characters than the others and the doing range(12) was pushing it out of bounds.